# IPEDS IDs on "Preliminary Loan Debt Data By Field of Study"?

Tags: collegescorecard

Frustratingly, the Program Debt Data found [here](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/preliminary/) does not include a column for IPEDS ID and the NAME column is not a 1:1 match with INSTNM from the other scorecard data. Does anyone have a version that includes either?

Answer (score 1):

This is a preliminary data file. In the final data files that will be released within the next few weeks, there will be a UNIT_ID column in both the institutional data as well as the program data that you can use to match.